# What is the behavior of spring boot if two routes are nearly identical?

Tags: spring-boot

I have two routes in the same class with following signatures in same order.

```
1>
@RequestMapping(value = "/useIndex", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<classname> getRatingOfComponentByUser(@RequestParam(value="name") String name, @RequestParam(value="userid") String user)

2>
@RequestMapping(value = "/useIndexes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<List<classname>> getRatingsOfComponent(@RequestParam(value="name") String name)
```

When I access `/useIndexes?name=starTrek`, It works fine and returns values.
But when I try `/useIndex?name=starTrek&userid=spock` it returns a 404, But from above it is clearly defined.

Am I missing some thing? is there any documentation to help with this case?

Comment: Did you check the logs on start up, is the above mappings showing in logs?

Comment: Thats an basic step and good idea I should have thought about. I will be more vigilant. Thanks

Comment: I think its a case of deploying multiple jars and playing wack a mole.

Comment: Happy to accept your answer if you put one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation names the parameter as userid (`@RequestParam(value="userid")`)

Try `/useIndex?name=starTrek&userid=spock`or change the definition to `@RequestParam(value="user")`